# Does the chat:write.public scope allow reading messages?

Tags: slack, slack-api

We are reviewing a Slack application for approval. The application is reqesting scope [chat:write.public](https://api.slack.com/scopes/chat:write.public) which is described by Slack as *"Send messages to channels @your_slack_app isn't a member of"*. If approved, would the app be able to read any message in any channel?

While both the name and text indicate that this is a write permission, I don't see any read messages permission in the request and I assume a bot can read its users' replies.

Here are all the requested permissions:
[image: App requested permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, in a raw state, an app will only be able to view messages that are sent to it. For anything else, it will require additional read permissions. The `chat:write.public` method applies only to public channels. With this scope an app and post to any *public* channel. To post into private channels the app/bot would need to be added into the channel as a member.

Comment: Thank you @sandra, if the app sends a message to a public channel it is not part of, will it be able to view responses to those messages (thread)?

Comment: Yes, the app will be able to see threaded responses to messages it posted.